# In Rails, is attr_accessible necessary for foreign key in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2, I have the following:

```
# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :nearby_shops
  after_update :find_nearby_shops

  def find_nearby_shops
    NearbyShop.create(
      :shop_id => self.id,
      :shop_type => "test",
    )
  end
end

# nearby_shop.rb
class NearbyShop < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :shop_id, :shop_type
  belongs_to :shop  
end
```

I find it was necessary to declare `shop_id` in `attr_accessible` to get the `shop_id` saved, else it would be blank. Is this behavior correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is. Otherwise you could use

```
def find_nearby_shops
  self.nearby_shops.create(
    shop_type: "test"
  )
end
```

`self.nearby_shops` will scope to the nearby_shops with current shop it and bypasses the protected attributes because you are not using a mass assignment method (such as `create`) to assign the `shop_id`.